# Include Reactjs application in EXTJS 3.0

Tags: reactjs, extjs

I am working with the ext js 3. Here I am planning to include the react application which is running on the Xampp server.

Below are the ways, which I have tried  to include. It shows the error.

<%@include file="index.html"%>

<jsp:include page="index.html" />

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to Senchs Docs for Ext JS component integration in React:

Unlock the Power of Ext JS in React! ReExt seamlessly integrates Sencha Ext JS components with your React Codebase, enabling the rapid development of modern and data-intensive applications.

- https://www.sencha.com/products/reext/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@gusmano/reext